# How to add font to paragraph from font-face file .ttf or .otf

Tags: css, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

We have a list of font's and need to apply to word dynamic from code, we have a URL "API" that return file content ".ttf" how we can apply it as font-face css to word document, i used the below code but word show warning **"Missing Font"**

```
Word.run(function (context) {
   console.log('start')
   var css = '<style>  @font-face {\n' +
           '    font-family: \'New_Font_001\';\n' +
           '    src: url(data:font/opentype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAANAIAAAwBQRkZUTX0L....) format(\'truetype\');\n' +
           '    font-weight: normal;\n' +
           '    font-style: normal;\n' +
           '}</style>';
context.document.body.insertHtml(css ,"Start");
context.document.body.paragraphs.load();
return context.sync().then(()=>{
  console.log('end')

  context.document.body.paragraphs.items[1].font.name="New_Font_001";



}).catch(e=> console.log(e));
```

})

Answer (score 1):

After some investigations, we found here is no API having such functionality as you expected for now and in recent future.

And here is another way to handle it. OOxml is a powerful way to change doc file indeed, but it is only applicable for those very experienced, has a bit unsatisfying performance online and may cause some problems hard to interpret. So in most cases, we don't recommend using ooxml to achieve one's goal actually. And we highly recommend you to refer to enough docs if you are interested in that because only insuring the correctness of code could support us to go on investigating.

At last, you can submit your request in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform if you really want new api.